# Execute command in graphical environment on tty1 via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, xfce

Allow me to elaborate some.

My grandmother is not the most competent woman with a computer but she likes to have access to the movies I have on an external hard drive.

I'd like to hook up a computer that has a graphical environment (ArchLinux-XFCE) up to her television via HDMI.  Is there anyway I can log in via SSH and queue up a video so it would play in the graphical environment without her having to do anything other than flip the TV to HDMI input and tell me which movie to queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! Just set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0` that every graphical command you make will be sent to the first open display (assuming that the TTY user and the graphical user are the same).

```
DISPLAY=":0" mplayer Movies/movie.ogv
```

Comment: you will also have to XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority

Comment: @sylvain.joyeux On my tests it wasn't necessary. Can you point me to a resource?